# Getting Class Rap2hpoutre LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider not found error in a school management software

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use [Unifiedtransform](https://github.com/changeweb/Unifiedtransform) a school management software in Github. I got this error `Class 'Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider' not found` while trying to run `composer install --no-dev`.

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

you try add in app dir. in providers dir in a,
 class LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider like this.done
https://github.com/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer/blob/master/src/Rap2hpoutre/LaravelLogViewer/LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider.php

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please try explaining about your proposed solution so that users can benefit from it. For knowing how to write good answers, please follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message while running a migration on a laravel project I cloned from GitHub.

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF73R.png)

I discovered that this file is part of the package rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer.
Please go to their [download page](https://php-download.com/package/rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer) to download this composer package.

You can also run the command below:

```
composer require rap2hpoutre/laravel-log-viewer
```

to solve the problem

> Class "Rap2hpoutre\LaravelLogViewer\LaravelLogViewerServiceProvider" not found